# VirtualFree with bad pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management, free

According to documentation first parameter of VirtualFree should be the same as pointer returned by VirtualAlloc:

> If the dwFreeType parameter is MEM_RELEASE, this parameter must be the
>   base address returned by the VirtualAlloc function when the region of
>   pages is reserved.

Looking at my code below, function VirtualFree can also success when I add offset 0 - FFF (0 - 4095).

Why is such call of VirtualFree not failing? Code below.

```
#include <Windows.h>
void main() 
{
    size_t size = 4*4096;

    VOID* ptr = (VOID*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!ptr)
    {
        printf("VirtualAlloc failed with status %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Pointer = %p\n", ptr);
    }

    printf("          ");
    scanf("%p", (VOID*)&ptr);
    printf("pointer = %p\n", ptr);

    BOOL status = VirtualFree(ptr, 0, MEM_RELEASE); 
    if (!status)
    {
        printf("VirtualFree failed with status %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("VirtualFree success\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return;
}
```

Comment: I don't think documentation says it must fail. Most likely rounds to page size, it is a very cheap operation to perform (just one bitwise &). But unless documentation explicitly says that, it shouldn't be relied upon (e.g. may be different for other kernel versions).

Comment: It is not doing what you expect it to do. I would consider that failing.